# SAS only include chi-square output in proc freq

Tags: sas, chi-squared

I'm using the following code to do a chi-square test in SAS.

```
proc freq data=data;
tables var1*var2/chisq;
run;
```

It gives the output of both chi-square and Fisher's Test. Anyway to only include chi-square test in the output?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ODS SELECT/EXCLUDE](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/05/28/five-reasons-ods-exclude.html) to control what is displayed. If you don't want the fishers test you can exclude that table, assuming the table name is FISHERSEXACT.

```
ods exclude fishersexact;
```

Alternatively you can select in only the tables you want and everything else is excluded by default.

```
ods select crosstabfreqs chisquare;
```

Comment: Might want to include the ODS TRACE advice Vojta gives in their answer here to make this more complete (as to how to identify which table is which)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can supress printing some of the tables in PROC FREQ; it seems to me you can supress all, or none.

However, still you can work as follows:

1. First, do a one-off investigation: issue the `ods trace on / label` before your statement so that the Log contains labels of the ODS tables:

```
ods trace on / label;
proc freq data=data;
tables var1*var2/chisq;
run;
ods trace off;
```

Alternatively, find the name of your table in [PROC FREQ docs](http://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=procstat&docsetTarget=procstat_freq_details124.htm&locale=en).

2. Once you know the table name, run your code again but this time save the respective ODS table to a regular table. This is done by issuing `ods output <ODS=table-name>= <table-to-save-it-into>;` in front of your command. Assuming you want to save the `ChiSq` table the code looks like:

```
ods output ChiSq=work.my_chisq_table;
proc freq data=data;
tables var1*var2/chisq;
run;
```

The chi-square table will be saved as `work.my_chisq_table` and you can print it elsewhere.

Comment: ODS SELECT/EXCLUDE allow you to control what tables and output is displayed and created.